# Select first valid datasource in VRT

Tags: gdal, elevation, gdalwarp, vrt, gdalbuildvrt

When reading data from a VRT, gdal appears to interpolate values from all available rasters. Is there a way to configure the VRT in such a way that it selects the first valid raster in the dataset, or is there a different raster format that would allow this?

I'm looking to migrate from ossim to gdalwarp, and ossim uses an ordered list of datasets when looking up elevation data. gdal's `RPC_DEM` [doesn't appear to support multiple dataset sources](https://gdal.org/api/gdal_alg.html?highlight=rpc_dem#_CPPv424GDALCreateRPCTransformerP11GDALRPCInfoidPPc) like ossim, so I've created VRTs for all our elevation datasets and one VRT combining all of them. Gdal, however, seems to interpolate between all available rasters, including low quality data that should only be used as a last resort, introducing unnecessary error:

```
$ for f in $(ls *.vrt); do echo $f; gdallocationinfo -wgs84 -valonly $f -117.5 33.75; done
1.vrt
458
2.vrt
456
3.vrt
458
4.vrt
460
5.vrt

6.vrt
621
merged.vrt
605
```

I've looked into [the documentation](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/vrt.html) and experimented with `SimpleSource` but didn't get anywhere. I think I can emulate it by masking each VRT in the list with the inverse of the previous VRTs, but that seems like it would be awfully complex, inefficient, and it may not work correctly near mask boundaries.

Comment: What your test should prove? As far as I know GDAL does not blend the images but selects them in the same order than they appear in the VRT. Sorting the VRT so that images with the best quality appear last in the VRT might work.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't very clear. In the merged VRT, which contains the numbered VRTs in order, a location query returns 605 meters which must be some interpolation of the VRTs when what I'd expect/want is the first VRT which is 458 meters.

Comment: Interestingly, reversing the order in the merged VRT returns 486 meters, so the order appears important to GDAL.

Comment: If you source files have overviews they may explain values which do not appear in the full resolution source data.